# How to extract certain text in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been racking my brain but cannot figure out exactly how to solve this issue.  I have column that "sometimes" contains a code within brackets [].  By sometimes, I mean that sometimes nothing is provide in the column, sometimes text but nothing withing [] is provided, and sometimes, multiple values are provided within the [], separated by a comma.  I am trying to fisgure out a select statement that will provide the result (either null, the single value within the brackets [], or the first value within the brackets [] (the one before the comma) regardless of how the data is provided (which I have no control over).

I have tried using substring, charindex, and left, and I am close, but I am missing "something".

```
select 
  [column5],
  case when CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) > 0 then
  SUBSTRING([column5], CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) + 1 , CHARINDEX(']', [column5]) - CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) -1)
  else null
  end,
  case when CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) > 0 then
  LEFT(SUBSTRING([column5], CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) + 1 , CHARINDEX(']', [column5]) - CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) -1), CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING([column5], CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) + 1 , CHARINDEX(']', [column5]) - CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) -1)))
  else null
  end
  FROM [Import].[dbo].[xx_LCM_EPC_IMP_CLI]
```

Examples of data in column 5 would be

Asthma exacerbation, severe persistent [J45.51].  The expectation is J45.51

Dermatochalasis of both upper eyelids [H02.831, H02.834]. The expectation is H02.831.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use some programming language to do that. Depending on which SQL implementation you're using, you could either write a builtin function that does that, or you could write a program that queries the database and than processes the data as needed.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.  Although I do have access to VB.NET, I would still face the same challenge of extracting the "correct" information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do what you want, this answer is for SQL SERVER.

```
SELECT [Column5]
    ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', T.t1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(T.t1,1,CHARINDEX(',',T.t1)-1) 
        ELSE T.t1 END AS [Value]
FROM (VALUES ('Asthma exacerbation, severe persistent [J45.51]'),('Dermatochalasis of both upper eyelids [H02.831, H02.834]'),('SoMe text here'),('SoMe text []'),('SoMe text [a,b,c,]')) AS Tbl([Column5])
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([column5],CHARINDEX('[', [column5]) + 1,CHARINDEX(']', [column5])-CHARINDEX('[', [column5])-1) 
                        ELSE NULL END)) AS T(t1)
```

Comment: Excellent.  This is exactly what I was looking for.